# How to load Web project in NetBean

Tags: web-inf, meta-inf

I have a web source code includes two folders: META-INF and WEB-INF directory is structured as:

WhatJobs

```
|META-INF
|WEB-INF
    |application
    |classes
    |framework
    |lib
    |resources
    |web.xml
```

how I can load project in NetBean. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Netbeans will need project property file by reading which, netbeans will be able to understand what type of project is. So either netbeans will check for the nbproject folder where in `project.properties` file will reside or it should be eclipse project where in netbeans can read eclipse project property file.

Your provided structure will not work.

If you want your project in netbeans, then you can create new project and copy paste files according to your requirement in that new project.